# Categories navigation portlet - users which are not logged in cannot see categories

Tags: permissions, liferay, categories

Categories navigation portlet - users which are not logged in cannot see categories in categories navigation portlet. I have tried to modify permissions but I wasnt able to resolve this problem.

Only signed users are abble to see categories in categories navigation portlet.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to give VIEW permission for GUEST role to categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create categories,it is when you choose who can see the categories and vocabulary.

**Liferay 6.2**:  Control Panel > Sites >click your site. Then in the left menu choose Content > Categories > Add category

**Liferay 6.1**:  Control Panel > Liferay > Categories (Add Vocabulary / Add Category)

**Add Vocabulary / Add Category**: At the end of the form, youn find a section: Permissions, where you can configure the permissions of the category, choosing which roles (guest, site member, owner).By default is Anyone(guest role)

When you include the "categories navigation portlet" in your site you should see them, unless you have different permissions.
Check this page, it can be useful for you:
https://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/tagging-and-categorizing-content-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-06-en

So try to do that:

1) Remove your "categories navigation portlet" of your page (because you said you change permissions)

2) Go to see your vocabularies and categories. You have to see the configure the permissions you have for them. (you should have Anyone(guest role))

3) Include again the "categories navigation portlet". (you must see your categories)

4) log off and check, you will see your categories too